# V-for with array of objects

Tags: vuejs2

I have an array of elements like this:

```
[
 'AKH-123': { ignition: true, position: { lat: 0, lng: 0},  },
 'VAW-123': { ignition: true, position: { lat: 1, lng: 1},  }
]
```

I want to show them using vfor. I have tried this:

```
        <gmap-marker
                :key="m.vehicle"
                v-for="(m, index) in vehicles"
                :position="vehicles[index].position"
                :icon="{url: getImagePath(m.ignition), scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(24, 24)}"
                v-if="show_live_vehicles"
        >
        </gmap-marker>
```

But this won't show vehicles on map. I am using vue2-google-maps component. I don't understand how do I pass in positions from keyed array

Comment: what is the name of your array declaration?

Comment: vehicles as you can see in v-for

Comment: can you give example value of `position`?

Comment: @Capt.Teemo DId you read my question?

Comment: yup. I'm talking about the `position` in <gmap-marker>. can you give static example?

Answer (score 0):

change this part of your code: `new google.maps.Size(24, 24)` to this `new google.maps.Size(m.position.lat, m.position.lng)`  or reverse the parms depending on the api.

This: `vehicles[index].position` could also just be `m.position` given that the two are equivalent.